# Switch to babel 7 and 'env'

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I switched to babel env and babel 7 beta, and renamed .babelrc.js, how should I add this config. How to apply this config. But I have an error 
Module build failed: C:\Users\server\Ui.babelrc.js:20
export default config
I had this .babelrc

```
    {
        "presets": [
            ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
            "react",
            "stage-1"
        ],
        "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"],
        "env": {
            "test": {
                "plugins": [
                    "istanbul"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I renamed to .babelrc.js

```
const config = {
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": ["last 1 versions", "ie >= 11"]
            },
            "modules": false
        }],
        "@babel/react",
        "@babel/stage-1"
    ],
    "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

if (nodeEnv === 'test')
    config.plugins.push('istanbul')

export default config
```

Comment: Fixed with module.exports = config, But still have questions is it ok practice like this one

Answer (score 0):

This approach is totally fine. The introduction of the `.babelrc.js` format [was actually what prompted the conversation](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4630) of "should env option be depreciated?".

Another option, check out [babel-preset-when](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-when) as described [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5276).